# Raspberry Pi checking and rebooting the main router if necessary

Tags: gpio, internet, script, monitoring

I have gotten tired of having to reboot my router a every other day.  I think my router does not update when my ISP changes.

Now I have a timer that cuts the powers to the router at 4 am.

An more elegant solution would be to ping a few different servers every second and if no response with in 30 s, then the router needs to reboot, by cutting the power to the router. Using the GPIO => Transistor => Relay.

What script is recommended, where to start. Is there something I can reuse so that I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

PS. I am an ASIC hardware designer, not a software guy.

Comment: How often do you change your Internet Service Provider? Every day?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you already can control the power switch via software? If so, you won't need more than a simple `bash` script: `ping` the servers with specified count and deadline. Depending on the exit status trigger the power switch. Run it via a cronjob.

Comment: Not really a Pi issue hence my vote - I would just look to change my ISP but failing that option just look to a remote control power plug.  Many types (eg HomeKit / Sonos / 433Mhz etc) have Pi versions

Answer (score 1):

You could do something as simple as `ping -q -c 1 -W 1 8.8.8.8 >/dev/null` and check the return code in a script. If your provider doesn't let ICMP through, you might want to make an HTTP request and check the response code like described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190615/106927):

```
case "$(curl -s --max-time 2 -I http://google.com | sed 's/^[^ ]*  *\([0-9]\).*/\1/; 1q')" in
  [23]) echo "HTTP connectivity is up";;
  5) echo "The web proxy won't let us through";;
  *) echo "The network is down or very slow";;
esac
```

Check out other answers on that page if you have problems with `curl`: you can query a web page using `nc`, `wget` and a bunch of other tools. If want to have a second opinion to avoid rebooting the router when Google is down, there is http://detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt

Run that script as a service or a `cron` job and replace the `echo` lines with commands that let you reboot your router.

- If you can hook a GPIO pin to a reboot circuit, then changing the pin state from a scrip can be done with `gpio mode <pin> out; gpio write <pin> [0/1]`.
- If your router has a web interface with a reboot URL, you can use the same tools (`curl`/`wget`/`nc`) to fetch that URL and trigger a reboot over the network.
- If your router has a javascript interface, you could use a headless browser such as [`phantomjs`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/phantomjs) to click through  the reboot sequence.